# I have some questions about kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, yaml, containers

[image]

when I use yaml file to deployment pods like this and use command `kubectl apply -f xx.yaml`

④image : nginx:latest

where does come from this Nginx image?

Is there any official Kubernetes documents about this?

Best Regards

Comment: its from dockerhub

Answer (score 2):

[Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) is a webserver that is used as an example for a pod template here.

`nginx:latest` refers to the nginx image on the [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

The `:latest` part refers to which version of nginx to use, in this case it picks the latest version.

You can read more about Kubernetes templates and container [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

Answer (score 1):

The general image name format is `<registry>/<image-name>:<tag>`.

Here, `nginx:latest` is in format of `<image-name>:<tag>` which refers registry is 
[dockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/). If you want to pull image from any other registry you have to put it in `<registry>` section. To learn more about images click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).